# DocumentCompleted not firing twice

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Scraping a web page.  The page loads and calls a DocumentCompleted handler.  Inside that handler, I invoke a java method to set a date and then invoke a click to get the new data (via POST).  This all works correctly except that the DocumentCompleted handler is only called once.  The POST that goes back and "gets" a new page doesn't cause the handler to fire a second time.

I tried adding multiple handlers, removing the first and adding a second handler in the first handler.  Didn't work.  Also ran this as Administrator, didn't change anything.

Anyone have thoughts on how to proceed?  I guess I can wait 60 seconds for it to load and then grab the text but that seems clunky.

```
    public void FirstHandler(object sender,
          WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = ((WebBrowser)sender);
        string url = e.Url.ToString();

        if (!(url.StartsWith("http://")) || url.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            // in AJAX
        }
        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != webBrowser.Url.AbsolutePath)
        {
            // IFRAME Painting
        }
        else
        {
            // really really complete
            wb.DocumentCompleted -= FirstHandler;
            wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(SecondHandler);

            HtmlElement webDatePicker = wb.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_WebSplitter1_tmpl1_ContentPlaceHolder1_dtePickerBegin");

            string szJava = string.Empty;
            szJava = "a = $find(\"ctl00_WebSplitter1_tmpl1_ContentPlaceHolder1_dtePickerBegin\"); a.set_text(\"5/20/2017\");";
            object a = wb.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { szJava });
            if (webDatePicker != null)
                webDatePicker.InvokeMember("submit");

            HtmlElement button = wb.Document.GetElementById("ctl00$WebSplitter1$tmpl1$ContentPlaceHolder1$HeaderBTN1$btnRetrieve");
            if (button != null)
            {
                button.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }

    public void SecondHandler(object sender, 
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = ((WebBrowser)sender);
        string url = e.Url.ToString();
        string d = string.Empty;

        if (!(url.StartsWith("http://")) || url.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            // in AJAX
        }
        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != webBrowser.Url.AbsolutePath)
        {
            // IFRAME Painting
        }
        else
        {
                d = wb.DocumentText;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Finally.htm", d);
                wb.DocumentCompleted -= SecondHandler;
        }
        _fired = true;
    }
```

Comment: Try two things:  First, comment out the unregistering of the FirstHandler from DocumentCompleted to see if it is an issue with your registration of the second handler.  This will create an infinite loop.but will tell you if the event is being raised or not.  Second, try registering the SecondHandler without the new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHander bit.

Comment: Ugh.  I looked and it appears that the click and POST results in a "panel update" being sent, not a new page.  That would explain why it isn't firing.  Now have to trap the panel update event.

Comment: if the timing of it is reliable, you can sleep the thread.  Otherwise there's no great way I've seen